# laravel-4 IF loop when relation is set

Tags: laravel-4, foreign-key-relationship

I have this relation in my Post model

```
public function mainItem()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Item', 'item_id');
}
```

Some of the Posts are connected to Item, some are not.

I can print the binding status with this line:

```
{{ $post->mainItem->id or 'not yet binded!'}}
```

I can even print image delivered through relation

```
<img src="{{ $post->mainItem->pic_filename or ''}}">
```

...and hide empty IMG with no SRC with the use of CSS3.

But how I can print a link or communique depending of the binding status?
I want to print a button which binds a post to an item - but the button should be visible only when the relation is not yet set.

```
@if($post->mainItem->count() > 0)
... here comes the button ...
@endif
```

The code works in case of a hasMany relation, but not in case belongsTo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return of a `belongTo` would be a single model. So to check this would be to check if the object `is_null`, as if there is no related model it will return null.

So this as you said for a `hasMany`;

```
@if($post->mainItem->count() > 0)
... here comes the button ...
@endif
```

And this for a `belongsTo`;

```
@if(is_null($post->mainItem))
.. Button
@endif
```

To find out more of the return types use the API found [here](http://www.laravel.com/api/4.2)